# Как в функцию передать буквально пустоту что бы сработало значение по умолчанию?

Tags: python

Могу ли я в python через переменную передать значение пустоты так что бы функция распознала это как не существующую переменную.

```
def fun(num=99): 
    print(num)
fun() # -> все работает

val=None 
del val
val="" 
val=False 

fun(val) # должен работать как fun()
```

Что бы я не пробовал функция все равно заменяет финальное значение.

Я хочу передать пустату что бы сделать значения по умолчанию между двумя функциями одинаковой без надобности копировать их из одной функций в другую

Простой пример

```
def test_1(val_1=5):
    print(val_1)

def test_2(val_2=???,val_3=9):
    test_1(val_2)
    print(val_2+val_3)

test_2() # Выведет 5 и 14
test_2(3) # Выведет 3 и 12
test_2(1,5) # Выведет 1 и 6
```

`val_1 == val_2`

Просто скопировать из функций `test_1(val_1=5):` в `test_2(val_2=5,val_3=9):`
нельзя

Я не могу менять код в функций `test_1` так как она загружается из модуля к которому у меня нет доступа редактирования.

Comment: По идее, наверное можно написать декоратор, который будет проверять аргументы функции и вызывать её без аргументов в определённых случаях. Но зачем это всё?

Answer (score 1):

```
def fun(num=None):
    if not num:
        num = 99
    print(num)
```

Или можно сделать условие

```
if num == None:
```

чтобы, например, 0 не попадал под него.

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто использовать

```
def fun(some=None,num=99):
    print(num)
fun()

val=None
fun(val)
```

Только зачем?

Answer (score 0):

Единственое что я нашел

```
def test_1(val_1=1, val_2=2, val_3=3, val_4=4, val_5=5):
    print("{}-{}-{}-{}-{}".format(val_1, val_2,val_3, val_4,val_5))


def test_2(rer="nj",*args, **kwargs):
    test_1(*args, **kwargs)
    print(rer)


test_2()
test_2('f','r','gt','g','h')
test_2('f', 'D')
test_2(val_2='D')
```

Где через **kwargs можно напрямую передавать аргументы в test_1

Answer (score 0):

```
def fix(func):
    def inner(arg):
        if arg is None:
            return func()
        else:
            return func(arg)
    return inner


@fix
def fun(num=99):
    print(num)
```

Через декоратор можно задать как угодно

fun(None) # будет работать как fun()